# Differentiating between user script input formats

Tags: scripting

I have a .NET project at work that provides a couple of (Iron)Python scripts to the customers, to allow them to customize the output of the program. The application generates code for certain machines, and supports a couple of different formats.

Until recently, we only provided a script for one format. We're expanding upon that to include support for the others.  If the user is using a script, they select their input script before generating the output code. A script designed for `Format1` output is going to cause errors if they're trying to generate `Format2` output. I need to deal with this.

One option would just be to let the customers use common sense, and if they load the wrong script it will just fail, or worse, produce inaccurate data. I'm inclined to provide a little more protection than that.

At the moment I'm considering putting a shebang-style comment line at the top of the script, ala:

```
# OUTPUT - Format1
```

If the user tries to run a `Format2` *process* with a `Format1` *script*, it will warn them. Alternatively I could create different file extensions for the input scripts that vary by type.

The file-type comment approach helps prevent the script from actually loading improperly, at the cost of failing to warn the user until they've already selected it, via a dialog box. Using different file extensions would allow me to cut down on visual clutter when providing a File Dialog, but doesn't actually stop them from loading the wrong script.

So I'm really not sure if the right approach is to just leave it alone, or provide some safeguards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one is answering, so I suppose I'll say what we ended up doing. We ended up putting a programmatic check in the script that ensures the process passed has the correct identifying attribute (in this case, an `Enum`, which `IronPython` can compare as a string). If a process with the wrong identifying `Enum` is passed the script will warn the user and terminate.

Nothing prevents the user from deleting that check from their own script. The same could be said for changing the file extensions or writing a shebang-type line. Nevertheless, it does seem to get the job done without putting in too much effort.